# C++ Programm Exe creates Error when starting

Tags: c++, crash

I tried to implement a c++ programm which should simply put out some text and create a txt-File and put data into this file. I would like to execute this file as .exe in Windows. But upon starting it crashes immediately shows following error:

[image: Error Window]

In English: "The program doesn't work anymore".

I coded this in CodeBlocks and I used GNU GCC Compiler.
I implemented the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;



int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world! TEST" << endl;
      std::ofstream of("TEXT.TXT");

        of<<"Some text here"<<std::endl;
        of.flush();
        of.close();
        std::cout<<"wrote the file successfully!"<<std::endl;
    cout << "TEST Done" << endl;
}
```

Debugger Info:

> D:/Dokumente/Devlopement/CodeBlocks/Test1/bin/Debug/Test1.exe
>   done
>   Registered new type: wxString
>   Registered new type: STL String
>   Registered new type: STL Vector
>   Setting breakpoints
>   Debugger name and version: GNU gdb (GDB) 7.6.1
>   Child process PID: 10052
>   Program received signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction.
>   In std::piecewise_construct () ()
>
> ## 1  0x0040147c in _fu0___ZSt4cout () at D:\Dokumente\Devlopement\CodeBlocks\Test1\main.cpp:10
>
> D:\Dokumente\Devlopement\CodeBlocks\Test1\main.cpp:10:86:beg:0x40147c
>   At D:\Dokumente\Devlopement\CodeBlocks\Test1\main.cpp:10
>
> ## 1  0x0040147c in _fu0___ZSt4cout () at D:\Dokumente\Devlopement\CodeBlocks\Test1\main.cpp:10

D:\Dokumente\Devlopement\CodeBlocks\Test1\main.cpp:10:86:beg:0x40147c

Compiler Version mingw32-gcc-g++ 5.3.0-3
In the past, when I first created the program I could not start it because some dlls were missing. I had to put it into the folder ( libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll,libstdc++-6.dll) Do they create the conflict?

Comment: Don't post screenshots. Please also clarify the C++ standard being used along with the compiler version.

Comment: Why should I not post screenshots? Excuse me. I edited post above

Comment: After trying to create `of`, you need to check that it was successful.

Comment: It is very hard to perform a web search for keywords that are embedded in an image; although, in this case the image adds little value to the question and you can easily do without it. If it contained diagnostic information, copy and paste the diagnostics into the question. If they can't be copied, you're usually better off typing them out than posting a screen-shot.

Comment: You probably have some type of dll conflict.

Comment: Code::Blocks contains a wrapper for gdb, a software debugger. This should help you pinpoint the crash. I see nothing in there that should trigger a crash. Set a failbit in `of`, maybe, but not crash.

Comment: I added the debugger info in the post above.

Comment: Take a look at the example [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/is_open/) to see how to add some error checking when using ofstream.

Comment: I added the error checking procedure like shown in exemaple, Trevor. Still the same error. I added more info above.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I had a problem with conflicting dlls. I put the option

> -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++

in the compiler options / linker settings / other linker options. It seems that the compiler now puts the correct dlls into the exe file and I don't need to put wrong conflicting dlls into the same path. Now it works perfectly.

Thank you.